# Online accounts - what is its purpose 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, empathy, online-accounts, social

Ok so I have put in my facebook etc into Online Accounts, but I don't understand what the integration is concerning my email and notifications, I see the Empathy messaging service which is cool I guess but surely I am missing someone, could someone link me somewhere/explain about the uses of online accounts and how they should be used

Comment: it's just a service for "sharing", "email", calendar" etc.   Check this maybe : http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/online-accounts/

Comment: Ok so it is basically just for other applications to be able to access your accounts, I am guessing there will be share to facebook apps and stuff in the USC